# Use variable for image url

Tags: php

I have this image `www.site.com/folder1/image1.jpg`, what I want to do is to access my image from a variable, for example `www.site.com/image.php?q=varForImage1`, it needs to work with `<img>` tag.
Example:
`<img scr="www.site.com/image.php?q=varForImage1">`

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, exactly? I mean, why do you _want_ that?

Comment: Is that a PHP or javascript variable?

Comment: I'd prefer php, but can work with javascript also

Comment: Well, a person could access `www.site.com/image.php?q=varForImage1` and get the image anyway....

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// define $image_path as required
$image_path;
header('Content-type:'.mime_content_type($image_path));
echo file_get_contents($image_path);
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<?php
$image = $_GET['q'];  
$file = fopen('/path/to/'.$image, 'rb');  
header("Content-Type: image/png");
```

Well, you should improve code of course, it may just give you an idea.